How to dynamically get the value of a variable in pyfmi
For example, this is my modelica model
model Test
  Real x(start = 1000);
  input Real k;
equation 
  der(x) = -k * x;
end Test;

from pyfmi import load_fmu

model = load_fmu('D:/FMU/Test.fmu')
model.initialize(0,10)

def f(time):
    global model
    x = model.get('x')
    return time*0.1

inputs = ('k', f)
result = model.simulate(final_time=10, input=inputs)

How can I get the value of x in function f，or how can I get the value of the current state and then adjust the input parameters to continue the simulation? I tried to get it via model.get(), but failed. Thanks a lot for your help！

I would like to reframe your question a little bit as follows:

Make simulation 1 and get the final value x and call it x1
Reset (or reload) the model
Enter the initial value of x as x1
Optionally change the parameter k
Make simulation 2 and get the final value x and call it x2
Plot the two simulations after each other

The model I change to this
model Test
  parameter Real k = 10;
  parameter Real x_start = 1000;
  Real x(start=x_start, fixed=true);  
equation
  der(x) = -k*x;
end Test;

And the script to this (and I use deprecated JModelica compiler to make the FMU, but instead the FMU can be made by for instance OpenModelica ver 1.25 or later)
# Setup framework
from pymodelica import compile_fmu 
from pyfmi import load_fmu
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Compile model
fmu_model = compile_fmu('Test','Test.mo', target='cs')

# Load model
model = load_fmu(fmu_model)

# Simulate
result1 = model.simulate(start_time=0, final_time=1)
x1 = model.get('x')

model.reset() 
model.set('k', 1)
model.set('x_start',x1)
result2 = model.simulate(start_time=1, final_time=2)
x2 = model.get('x')

# Plot results
plt.figure()
plt.semilogy(result1['time'], result1['x'])
plt.semilogy(result2['time'], result2['x'])
plt.xlabel('Time'); plt.ylabel('x'); plt.grid()
plt.show()


Hope this address your main question?
Note, that the method can be easily generalised for continuous time systems. A dictionary of all the continuous time states can be obtained by the PyFMI-command
model.get_states_list()

For further inspiration on how to handle the more general case, take a look at the example on my Github page
https://colab.research.google.com/github/janpeter19/BPL_TEST2_Batch/blob/main/BPL_TEST2_Batch_colab.ipynb
run the example, and in cell 17 you see application of continued simulation after a parameter change. Also take a look at the Python setup file BPL_TEST2_Batch_explore.py
where you find the code for simu(,'cont').
Here is in the FMI-standard a procedure to get and set the total state of an FMU, i.e. including both continuous and discrete time states and more.
model.get_fmu_state()
model.set_fmu_state()

However, the FMUs generated by OpenModelica (or deprecated JModelica) does not support this functionality. Therefore, the approach described above has a place.

An alternative solution is to describe the values of parameter k over time in a table  and then just have one simulation, instead of two. The advantage of changing the parameter from a table in Modelica is that the total execution time is slightly shorter. The drawback is if you have a large system with many parameter, then you need more tables. During explorative testing of impact of various parmeters of a larger model, the interactive command-line approach first described provides desired flexibility.
Modelica comes with Modelica Standard Library and here is a module called CombiTimeTable that I use in the further modified example below.
The updated model is
model TestWithTable

   import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput;
   import Modelica.Blocks.Sources;
   import Modelica.Blocks.Types;

   model Test
      RealInput k;
      parameter Real x_start = 1000;
      Real x(start=x_start, fixed=true);
   equation
      der(x) = -k*x;
   end Test;

   Test test;

   Sources.CombiTimeTable table(
      smoothness=Types.Smoothness.ConstantSegments,
      extrapolation = Types.Extrapolation.HoldLastPoint,
      table=[0,10; 1,1]);   

equation
   
   connect(table.y[1], test.k);

end TestWithTable;

And the updated script is
# Setup framework
from pymodelica import compile_fmu 
from pyfmi import load_fmu
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Compile model
fmu_model = compile_fmu('TestWithTable','TestWithTable.mo', target='cs')

# Load model
model = load_fmu(fmu_model)

# Simulate
result = model.simulate(start_time=0, final_time=2)

# Plot results
plt.figure()
plt.semilogy(result['time'], result['test.x'])
plt.xlabel('Time'); plt.ylabel('x'); plt.grid()
plt.show()


I hope you like it!
You can read more about the MSL CombiTimeTable here
https://doc.modelica.org/Modelica%204.0.0/Resources/helpDymola/Modelica_Blocks_Sources.html#Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable
And you can see an example of the usage of CombiTimeTable on my Github page https://github.com/janpeter19/BPL_TEST2_Chemostat
by running the example. In cell 13 you see the process_diagram and the icon for the CombiTimeTable called schemePumps you see on the left. The parameter values for the table you see by the command disp('schemePumps', mode='long') and you can change a parameter with the command par() as done with other parameters.

For the sake of completeness, I show a third solution below. It is more closer related to your own attempt using "input =" in the simulation call.  The same model as in the first solution is used. The script is as follows.
# Setup framework
from pymodelica import compile_fmu 
from pyfmi import load_fmu
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Compile model
fmu_model = compile_fmu('Test','Test.mo', target='cs')

# Load model
model = load_fmu(fmu_model)

# k variation
eps = 0.05
k_data = np.transpose(np.vstack([np.array([0,1-eps, 1+eps, 2]), np.array([10, 10, 1, 1])]))

# Simulate
result = model.simulate(input=('k', k_data) , start_time=0, final_time=2)

# Plot results
plt.figure()
plt.semilogy(result['time'], result['x'])
plt.xlabel('Time'); plt.ylabel('x'); plt.grid()
plt.show()


Note 1, that the k_data is interpreted using linear interpolation and here I choose to make a change between time 1-eps to 1+eps and you can see in the result above that the change of the k-parameter is not as abrupt as in the two previous solutions. (Choose a smaller eps and the k-parameter change becomes more abrupt).
Note 2, that in the model used (see the first solution) it would be more proper to declare "input Real k" instead of "parameter Real k", but both works.
A guiding example 4.4 can be found in
https://lucris.lub.lu.se/ws/portalfiles/portal/7201641/pyfmi_tech.pdf
This document from 2016 is still a good concise introduction to PyFMI that follows the FMI 2.0 standard.

Well, a fourth solution (with the first model), and even more similar to your first attempt.
# Setup framework
from pymodelica import compile_fmu 
from pyfmi import load_fmu
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Compile model
fmu_model = compile_fmu('Test','Test.mo', target='cs')

# Load model
model = load_fmu(fmu_model)

# k variation
def f(time):
   if time < 1:
      k = 10
   else: 
      k = 1
   return k

# Simulate
result = model.simulate(input=('k', f) , start_time=0, final_time=2)

# Plot results
plt.figure()
plt.semilogy(result['time'], result['x'])
plt.xlabel('Time'); plt.ylabel('x'); plt.grid()
plt.show()


I actually think this solution has a flexibility comparable with the first solution and useful for explorative simulation work. The first solution brings more concise notebook notation, but requires investment in background Python code, what I call FMU-explore.
The four different solutions have each an advantage in general and therefore I think I let them stay posted.
I think I learnt something myself working through these different solutions!
